# Why ArrayList is faster than HashSet when I want to insert data in them?

Tags: list, collections, set

Time to insert 10,000,000 elements in ArrayList 2,245 seconds
Time to insert 10,000,000 elements in HashSet 6,401 seconds

the implementation is very simple a for loop to insert 10_000_000 elements.

I want to know why the Sets implementation is lower than the List implementation when I call the add method.

`for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) { collection.add(RandomStringGenerator.generateRandomString()); }`

Comment: The list does not have to test membership, calculate hash codes, determine hash bucket!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting to an ArrayList is very simple, its just an index.  HashSet is backed by a HashMap and while its O(1) as well, it does need to compute a hash key.

Its also worth noting that a test like this would be effected by the machine as well as the exact implementation of the hashset.